# Does PHP negation check with `!` coprrespond to `!=` or to `!==`?

Tags: php, boolean, operators, operator-precedence, negation

In PHP, is

```
if(!$foo)
```

equivalent with

```
if($foo != true)
```

or with

```
if($foo !== true)
```

or is it even something completly different of both?

Comment: all of them are same!

Comment: a simple run can give you the right answer.

Comment: See also [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!$foo)
```

is the equivalent to

```
if($foo != true)
```

so

```
$foo = null;
if(!$foo){
 echo "asd";
}
```

will ouptut "asd"

Answer (score 4):

Note that,

**`==` OR `!=` compares the values of variables for equality, type casting as necessary. `===` OR `!==` checks if the two variables are of the same type AND have the same value.**

This answer will give you better explanation of this concept:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/3067928

Comment: I'm not asking about the difference between `==` and `===` (or their negations), which I know. I'm asking about their relation to `!`.

Answer (score -1):

**$a != $b**

TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.

**$a !== $b**

TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.

---

See [type juggling in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for more info on type juggling.

---

Sources : php.net

Comment: I'm not asking about the difference between `==` and `===` (or their negations), which I know. I'm asking about their relation to `!`.

Answer (score -1):

Its not the same

```
!= is No equal (Returns true if  is not equal)
!== is Not identical  (Returns true if  is not equal , or they are not of the same type)
```

Comment: I'm not asking about the difference between `==` and `===` (or their negations), which I know. I'm asking about their relation to `!`.